# Pjsip Failed to discconect audio

Tags: python, pjsip

Im using Python pjsip library but i have some issue disconnecting the WAV playing before answer the call
this is the code

```
 if self.call.info().state == pj.CallState.EARLY:
                    call_slot = self.call.info().conf_slot
                    self.wav_player_id = pj.Lib.instance().create_player('ring.wav', loop=True)
                    self.wav_slot = pj.Lib.instance().player_get_slot(self.wav_player_id)
                    pj.Lib.instance().conf_connect(self.wav_slot, 0)


if self.call.info().state == pj.CallState.CONFIRMED:
                    print "connecting"
                    pj.Lib.instance().conf_disconnect(self.wav_slot, 0)
                    pj.Lib.instance().player_destroy(self.wav_player_id)
```

any ideas whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

When you disconnect the slot, shouldn't you wait for a disconnected callback before destroying the player ?

Comment: no Im disconnecting on CONFIRMED Callback because im using this to put the calling tone (ring) for the caller , after that i connect the sound device to microphone and speakers , but the ringing keep on the sound device and the call too

Answer (score 0):

i already solved 
the problem is EARLY is repeating 2 times and create two players

so the correct method is CALLING to put the wav to play